# ActionLink with /Controller/Action/Id/Id2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I have an action link with two Ids. (I am using areas). The Id2 gets rendered as a querystring.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult View(int id, int id2)
```

**Route**

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default2",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}",
    new { action = "Index"}
);
```

**ActionLink**

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click", "News/View", new { area = "Admin", id = 1, id2 = 2 }, null)
```

**Rendered Link**

```
/Admin/News/View/1?id2=2
```

**Expected Link**

```
/Admin/News/View/1/2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the more specific route (Admin_default2) first.

So, your mapping code would look like:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default2",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{id2}",
    new { action = "Index"}
);

context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```